# Java 8 Deferring Execution of Method

Tags: java, callback, java-8, deferred, callable

I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo {
    abstractMethod(/*parameters*/) {
        //do something;
    }
}

public class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
    public String doSomething(int id, int value, FooB b, FooC c) {
        //do something;
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        abstractMethod(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to pass the `doSomething` method as a method parameter to `abstractMethod`. I tried something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo {
    abstractMethod(/*parameters*/, Callable<String> method) {
        //do something;
        method.call();
    }
}

public class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
    Callable<String> doSomething = (int id, int value, FooB b, FooC c) -> {
        //do something;
    };

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        abstractMethod(param1, param2, doSomething);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:(37, 40) java: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression: wrong number of parameters: expected 0 but found 4
```

So clearly I'm not doing this correctly. What exactly is the proper Java 8 way to achieve what I want?

**Edit 1:** Based on comments, here is an attempt at a better solution:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Fazz<T> {
    String createStuff(int id, int value, T value1, T value2);
}

public abstract class AbstractFoo {
    abstractMethod(Fazz<T> interfc) {
        interfc.createStuff(/* pass parameters? */);
    }
}

public class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
    Fazz<String> doSomething = (int id, int value, String value1, String value2) -> {
        //do something;
    };

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        abstractMethod(doSomething);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's sort of un-clear what and why you are doing things like this... you could define either a `@FunctionalInterface` with 4 arguments, or pass the arguments as parameters and still pass a single `Callable`; but it makes little sense for me either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface has only one method: `call()` which takes zero arguments, hence the error.

If you want to be able to pass a lambda you should implement a [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), for example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface DoSomething<T> {
    T doSomething(int id, int value, FooB b, FooC c);
}
```

and then you'll be able to create and pass such a lambda:

```
DoSomething<String> doSomething = (int id, int value, FooB b, FooC c) -> {
        //do something (that returns a string)
};
```

Further, a `Callable` is used to run logic in a separate thread. The code that you posted above does not do that, which means that you can do the exact same work without using a `Callable`.

In case you *do* want to run this logic in a separate thread, you can create a `Callable` that calls `doSomething`. Still, in order to run it in a separate thread you should use an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Pay attention: a `FunctionalInterface` can have only *one* abstract method (it can have additional default methods - since they are not abstract).

Comment: so I need to create this interface, then implement it in my `Foo` class?

Comment: @Richard yes. The lambda *is* the implementation, and you can implement it where ever you need!

Comment: Note that the way your functional interface is declared you should declare the method signature of createStuff to return T not a string.

Comment: i still have no idea how to actually implement any of this

Comment: @Richard you make it hard for me to help you: saying "I'm not doing something right" and "I have no idea" is too vague... If you'll use the code in the answer above it should work, if it doesn't, you should provide more info: is it a compilation error? if so - what's the error and from which line is it triggered? is it a runtime error? if so, what's the stacktrace and which line causes it? help us help you!

Answer (score 1):

The way lambda expressions is used in Java, *require* that a functional interface is used in your method to call, and the lambda expression must implement that.  This mean that the functional interface must take the number of arguments that the lambda expression need.   It can only be void or return a single value.

If you need four arguments, there is no standard interface that can do that for you (Callable does not take an argument).  You can easily define your own; look at BiFunction to see how you should define a QuadFunction.